# How can i show json data in table in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have dataset in `json` data format.All i want is to be able to show the data in the table.I used the `v-for` pattern but I couldn't show the data in the table this way I am using tailwind css.But it doesn't work. Any advice. Thanks in advance !

Template

```
       <table
    class="table-auto w-3/5 text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
  >
    <thead
      class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400"
    >
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">id</th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">name</th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">age</th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6">costs</th>
        <th scope="col" class="py-3 px-6"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr
        v-for="unit in units"
        :key="unit.id"
        class="bg-white border-b"
      >
        <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium whitespace-nowrap">
          {{ unit.id }}
        </th>
        <td class="py-4 px-6">{{ unit.name }}</td>
        <td class="py-4 px-6">{{ unit.age }}</td>
        <td class="py-4 px-6">{{ unit.cost }}</td>
        <td class="py-4 px-6 text-right">
          <router-link
            to="#"
            class="font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline"
            Detail
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Script

```
import json from "@/dataset/age-of-empires-units.json";
export default {
  name: "Units-List",
  components: {
    CostsFilter,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      units: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.units = json;
  },
};
```

Json dataset

```
    {
      "units": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Archer",
          "description": "Quick and light.",
          "expansion": "Age of Kings",
          "age": "Feudal",
          "cost": {
            "Wood": 25,
            "Gold": 45
          },
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Crossbowman",
          "description": "Upgraded archer",
          "expansion": "Age of Kings",
          "age": "Castle",
          "cost": {
            "Wood": 25,
            "Gold": 45
          },
        },
     ]
   }
```

Directory

[image]

Comment: surely you need some cells (td) in each row (tr)

Comment: `<td>{{unit.id}}</td><td>{{unit.name}}</td><td>{{unit.age}}</td>` etc

Comment: @JaromandaX Can u check again questions? I edited but it doesn't show on table

Comment: no errors? the `<router-link` looks wrong having the word `Detail` as an attribute, but I doubt that would stop the table from displaying - check for errors, and check to see what `json` is

Comment: @JaromandaX ı removed router link code part but still i cant display data in table

Comment: you addressed the only part I said wouldn't be a problem - what about errors? what about the content of json? these are the things that will stop you

Comment: @JaromandaX strange that I don't see any errors in console. Json format actually as I posted in the question

Comment: If you view the source code of the page in the browser what does it look like